# Airflow - Stop DAG based on condition (skip remaining tasks after branch)

Tags: python, bigdata, airflow

I am new on airflow, so I have a doubt here.

I wanna run a DAG if a condition on first task is satisfied. If the condition is not satisfied I wanna to stop the dag after the first task.

Example:

```
# first task
def get_number_func(**kwargs):

    number = randint(0, 10)
    print(number)
    
    if (number >= 5):
        print('A')
        return 'continue_task'
    else:
        #STOP DAG
        
# second task if number is higher or equal 5
def continue_func(**kwargs):
    print("The number is " + str(number))
    
# first task declaration
start_op = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='get_number',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_number_func,
    op_kwargs={},
    dag=DAG,
)

# second task declaration
continue_op = PythonOperator(
    task_id='continue_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=continue_func,
    op_kwargs={},
    dag=DAG,
)

start_op  >> continue_op
```

I only run the second task if the condition of number is satisfied. In case of condition is not verified the DAG should not run the second task.

How can I perform that? I don't wanna use xcom, global variables or a dummy task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define what you meany by stop the DAG. are you referring to the specific run? Do you mean to finish the workflow with success?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you checked out the [`ShortCircuitOperator`](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/shortcircuitoperator)?  This task controls your task flow depending on whether a condition is True or False.  If the condition is True, the downstream tasks will continue.  Otherwise, all downstream tasks are skipped.  Try changing your first task to a `ShortCircuitOperator` and update the `get_number_func` function to return True or False.

Here was my test using your code:

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, ShortCircuitOperator

from datetime import datetime


default_args = dict(
    start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 26),
    owner="me",
    retries=0,
)

dag_args = dict(
    dag_id="short_circuit",
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
)


def get_number_func(**kwargs):
    from random import randint

    number = randint(0, 10)
    print(number)

    if number >= 5:
        print("A")
        return True
    else:
        # STOP DAG
        return False


def continue_func(**kwargs):
    pass


with DAG(**dag_args) as dag:
    # first task declaration
    start_op = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id="get_number",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=get_number_func,
        op_kwargs={},
    )

    # second task declaration
    continue_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id="continue_task",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=continue_func,
        op_kwargs={},
    )

    start_op >> continue_op
```

Comment: Hi Josh, that is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! God Job!

Comment: You're welcome!  Would you mind choosing this as the accepted answer? Would be helpful for others in the future.